# SQL Server Insert performance 20x slower in 2012 vs. 2008

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, insert, sql-server-2012

I've searched to no avail for an understanding as to why the exact same query run in SSMS 2008 performs 20 times faster than that run in SSMS 2012.

Trying to insert 1000 records, SQL Server 2012 takes almost **10 seconds** where SQL Server 2008 takes about **~500ms**.

This is what the insert looks like:

```
Create Table RmtTagValue2 
( 
     ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
     TagID INT, 
     Value decimal(18,5), 
     Time datetime, 
     Timestamp INT, 
     Status INT, 
     DescriptorID INT, 
     GroupUpdateID INT, 
     Timestamp_nano INT
)

DECLARE @nInx INT
SET @nInx = 1

WHILE (@nInx <= 1087)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RmtTagValue2 (TagID, Value, Time, Timestamp, Status, DescriptorID, GroupUpdateID, Timestamp_nano)
    VALUES (@nInx, 33.0, 1234567, 1118887776, 0, 1, 5, 77766655)

    SET @nInx = @nInx + 1
END

SELECT * FROM RmtTagValue2
```

My question is: what (setting?) am I missing in SQL Server 2012 so that it inserts the above in a similar amount of time to that of 2008?

Comment: A 20x perf difference due to server versions is kind of hard to believe. What else is different between the two servers? Also if you were using a transaction here you'll probably realize a further 10x perf gain. In fact the 2012 takes 10ms per row which looks like the time it takes to perform a disk seek. *Are* you using a transaction on 2008?!

Comment: @usr Thanks for the response, I agree the server shouldn't be the issue but maybe default settings are a factor?  To answer your question, I'm using the exact code above on both 2008 and 2012 - so I'm not (explicitly) using a transaction.

Comment: There is no 20x turbo button in SQL Server. There is no single setting that can make this trivial workload that much slower. Post both actual execution plans (set the loop trip count to 1 so that they don't explode in size). Use SET NOCOUNT ON.

Comment: FYI - I did try using the above in a transaction and @usr is correct - the performance on 2012 improves dramatically... under 1 second.  But  I'd still like to understand why, without the transaction, is the performance so different between 2008 and 2012??

Comment: Are both database log files on similar storage? Maybe 2008 on SSD? 99% of the time here is spent doing disk seeks to write the log. One seek per row. On SSDs (or hardware caches) the writes are quick.

Comment: @usr I posted the execution plans - they're identical.  As for disk storage type, I _believe_ they're the same...  Locally I am running 2008 on a VM whose host hardware has HDD and SSD.  The VM image is stored on HDD, while the VM software runs from the SSD - I thought this would mean the DB writes are stored to the VM image (which is on HDD drive).  To eliminate this unknown, I ran the query on another 2008 server which I am sure is an HDD.  Again that result, was consistent with 500ms.  The 2012 machines are HDD drives.

Comment: I suspect it's storage. You are not quit sure where the data really goes... Honestly, this is something you should investigate now to the point where you are 100% certain. Also investigate hardware caches and the Windows disk cache policy. Maybe the VM software has a write-back cache as well. If writes are not durable right now you might be exposed to data loss in case of power loss.